# Using slices and Arrays in go error

Tags: arrays, go

I am learning go and I am used to using Java so I am running into errors than in my mind don't seem to be a problem.  Here is my code:

```
package main
import(
    "fmt"
)

func main(){
    f:= [5]int{1,2,3,4,5}
    h:= [5]int{6,7,8,9,10}

    fmt.Println(reverseReverse(f,h))

}
func reverseReverse(first []int, second []int) ([]int, []int){
    //creating temp arrays to hold the traversed arrays before swapping.
    var tempArr1 []int
    var tempArr2 []int
    //count is used for counting up the tempArrays in the correct order in the For loops
    var count = 0
    //goes through the first array and sets the values starting from the end equal to the temp array
    //which increases normally from left to right.
    for i :=len(first)-1; i>=0;i--{
        tempArr1[count] = first[i]
        count++
    }
    count =0
    //same as first for loop just on the second array
    for i :=len(second)-1; i>=0;i--{
        tempArr2[count] = second[i]
        count++
    }
    //trying to replace the values of the param arrays to be equal to the temp arrays
    first=tempArr2
    second = tempArr1
    //returning the arrays
    return first,second
}
```

Basically I am trying to write a method that takes two arrays and returns them reversed and swapped.

Ex:

```
arr1 = {1,2,3}

arr2 = {6,7,8}
```

should return:

```
arr1 = {8,7,6}

arr2 = {3,2,1}
```

My error that I am getting is as such :

> src\main\goProject.go:35: cannot use first (type [5]int) as type []int
>   in return argument
>
> src\main\goProject.go:35: cannot use second (type [5]int) as type
>   []int in return argument

It says: Cannot use f (type [5]int) as type []int on the variables in my print statement.

I had problems before and swapped my tempArrays to be slices, but I don't understand why I am getting this error.

Side note: I tried replacing the parameters array lengths to ... with no luck either:

```
func reverseReverse(first [...]int, second [...]int) ([]int, []int){
```

This created the same error as before just says:

```
f (type [5]int) as type [...]int
```

So my question is: why am I getting this error?  This is all the code I have comment any questions for more info if need be.

Here:

Before I changed the temp array to a slice I had this:

```
var tempArr1 [len(first)]int
var tempArr2 [len(second)]int
```

I still get the same error as stated before, but the new error is:

src\main\goProject.go:15: non-constant array bound len(first)

src\main\goProject.go:16: non-constant array bound len(second)

And I understand it should be constant, but why is using len() not make it constant?

Comment: `[]int` and `[5]int` are different types. Just use slices throughout. Your errors don't correspond to the source you posted, but getting rid of the arrays will fix them anyway.

Comment: @JimB I want it to use arrays though and when I used all arrays I got errors as well, is there a way I can use all arrays?  I will edit it to show what it was like without splices and the errors I got.

Comment: I edited it to show what it was before the splices.  I want to do with with arrays if possible I am sure splices would work too, but I wanted to do it with arrays for proof of concept.

Comment: `(first [...]int, second [...]int)` isn't valid syntax, which the compiler will tell you. Your arguments are slices, so either make them arrays or use slices throughout.

Comment: Check the edit, I made them all arrays and I still have the same problem with more.

Comment: you have not made them all arrays; the only arrays in the source are `f` and `h`

Comment: looking at the edits, `var tempArr1 [len(first)]int` isn't valid either, again the compiler will tell you this.

Comment: I know it isnt valid can you explain to me why?  I don't know why that is wron g

Comment: It says `non-constant array bound`. Arrays size must be a constant, as it's part of the type. Arrays are fixed values and can't be dynamically sized.

Comment: There we go ok so the len() method doesn't count as constant.

Comment: By definition, constants are known at compile time. `len()` is evaluated at runtime, therefor cannot be constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of issues:

- You have to make a slice with a length of 5 before you can access elements in it. You'll panic if you simply do var tempArr1 []int
- You can use slices instead of arrays, and your return types will match with []int

You'll find your fix here:
https://play.golang.org/p/5E2hL0796o

Edit: to allow you to keep your data types as an array, simply change your return types to match. Your function signature should look like this:

```
func reverseReverse(first [5]int, second [5]int) ([5]int, [5]int)
```

GoPlay here:
https://play.golang.org/p/_eV3Q0kspQ

To answer your question, you cannot have a function take in an array of arbitrary size. You would have to specify the length. There is a fundamental difference in Go for []int and [5]int.

Comment: Can you see my edit.  I wanted to try to do it with only arrays and I changed it to splices to try to solve error from using all arrays.  Is it possible to do it with all arrays? Please see edits.  If I have to use splices then I can get over than just curious if I can with only arrays.

Comment: So I am understanding that if I don't know the size of the array I will be getting I have to use a splice, but there is no way to use an array as a param without specifying the the length?

Comment: Again I am used to java where I can say the param is an array[] of length whatever I am given.

Comment: An array has a fixed length, a slice has variable length. You can get a slice of an array `myArray` with `myArray[:]`, which is the slice of all elements in the array.

Comment: You can use arrays or slices anywhere, but if you're using arrays, you have to specify the length.

Comment: But to be clear, len(first) is not specifying the length?  This is considered variable to go?

Comment: @HoldenMalinchock that is correct. In addition, the reason your attempt with "var tempArr1 [len(first)]int" doesn't work is because arrays are fixed (read constant): https://golang.org/ref/spec#Array_types